# strange sql error

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

i have the following code:

```
<!--ajouter une carte     -->
<?php
if($_POST["submit_dd"]){

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO data SET desc='".$_POST["carte_nom"]."' ") or die(mysql_error());



 }
?>

<b>Ajouter une carte:</b><br>
<form method="post">
<table>
<tr><td>nom</td><td><textarea name="carte_nom"/></textarea></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" name="submit_dd" value="Ajouter"/></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

i get an error from this very simple query:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc='dsfgsdfds'' at line 1
```

the database is very simple: id(primary, auto increment), desc(text)

regards

Comment: *waits for the comments about SQL injection*

Comment: hmmm... looks like you could have a sql injection problem there ;)

Comment: Try using prepared statements and placeholders. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might be wrong, but you are probably getting an error because `desc` is a sql keyword. try wrapping it in back ticks `desc`

Answer (score 1):

`desc` is a reserve keyword. Use `"desc"` instead

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO data (desc) VALUES('".$_POST["carte_nom"].")' ")
```

Comment: yeah, I was just editing my answer to suggest placeholders and prepared statements, but I will just make a comment.

Answer (score 0):

[Check the list of reserved keywords.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-0.html)  "DESC" is one of them.

The following is valid in MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO data SET `desc` = 'post data';
```

You should rethink your script though.  Having fields named the same as reserved keywords is a bad sign.  As is the lack of sanitation before using the $_POST data.

Here's why `desc` is an ugly fieldname:

```
SELECT id, desc
FROM data
ORDER BY id desc;  #this is valid sql, but likely isn't going to do what you expect
```

Which look very much like

```
SELECT id, desc
FROM data
ORDER BY id, desc;   #not valid sql
```

And the obligatory injection reading:  [How does the SQL injection from the "Bobby Tables" XKCD comic work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain)